# batch file - find string in files with substring of filename and replace it

Tags: batch-file

I would like to ask you, how can I do this:
I have three files in folder, `car.txt`, `bus.txt`, `plane.txt`. File `car.txt` contains some text with string for example `test="in_car`" and I know, that I find word with prefix "`in_`" + word from filename "`car`" and if I find it, I want to replace it by word "`hello`". And for files `bus.txt` and `plane.txt` do same thing, find word `in_bus` and replace it by `hello` etc. And I know that prefix "`in_`" is only at this place.
Please, can you help me?

I try something like this:

```
for /R "../myFolder" %%f in (*.txt) do ( 
    set FILENAME=%%~nf
    set PREFIX=in_
    set REPLACETEXT=hello
    SET string=%%A
    set modified=!string:%PREFIX%%FILENAME%=%REPLACETEXT%!
)
```

but it is not working and I don't know, how can I save it to current file (replace it in file)

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: I try something like this:
for /R "../myFolder" %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set FILENAME=%%~nf
    set PREFIX=in_ 
    set REPLACETEXT=hello    
    SET string=%%A
    set modified=!string:%PREFIX%%FILENAME%=%REPLACETEXT%!
)
but it is not working and I don't know, how can I save it to current file (replace it in file)

Comment: Please don't post code snippets in comments; [edit] your question instead. I did it for occasion.

Comment: Why the heck does such a problem need to be solved with a batch ? Use a real programming language for this or at least Windows scripting host which is present on current versions of Windows.

Comment: Please show where `%%A` comes from...

Answer (score 1):

you forgot another `for` (to read the files) (although you obviously planned it, as you used `%%A`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set PREFIX=in_
set REPLACETEXT=hello
for /R  "." %%f in (*.txt) do ( 
    set FILENAME=%%~nf
    (for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%f) do (
        SET string=%%A
        set modified=!string:%PREFIX%%%~nf=%REPLACETEXT%!
        echo !modified!
        REM echo !string:%PREFIX%%%~nf=%REPLACETEXT%!
    ))>%%~dpnf.new
)
```

Comment: 1. this might fail if there are spaces in the file names, or also special characters like `&` and `^`; 2. what's the `REM` line for?

Answer (score 0):

so I have this function solution:

```
pushd "../myFolder"
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "FILENAME=%%~nf"
set "OUTPUT=%%~nxf"
set "PREFIX=in_" 
set "REPLACETEXT=hello"   
set "TEMP=tmp"

for /R %%f in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%f) do (
        SET "string=%%A"
        SET modified=!string:%PREFIX%%FILENAME%=%REPLACETEXT%! 
        echo !modified! >> %TEMP%
    )   
    del %OUTPUT%
    rename %TEMP% %OUTPUT%  
)
popd
```

but there is still one problem, I have not character ! in summary of output file, one line contains < !-- (without space,but I can't write it right here) but in output I have only this <--

Comment: I have it! I set "setLocal" to disable and if for cycle I enable it :) thank you all so much :)